# webserver based on node.js couldn't parse the right data which sent by method 'POST' via CURL

Tags: c++, node.js, libcurl

I implemented a simple webserver based on node.js, which handle the data
sent by method 'POST' via libCURL.

Client: c++ code based on libCURL
Server: Node.js

> > > Result:

#### Client

I implemented a simple webserver based on node.js, which handle the data
sent by method 'POST' via libCURL.

Client: c++ code based on libCURL
Server: Node.js

```
###Client####
>>>
* Found bundle for host 109.123.121.146: 0x1b13f00 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host 109.123.121.146
* Connected to 109.123.121.146 (109.123.121.146) port 8124 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 109.123.121.146:8124
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 11

* upload completely sent off: 11 out of 11 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
< Date: Thu, 05 Jan 2017 21:14:05 GMT
Date: Thu, 05 Jan 2017 21:14:05 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

< 
* Connection #0 to host 109.123.121.146 left intact


###Server####
####### 'POST' ######
Partial body:  B=~�  size:11
Body:  B=~�   size:11   ---->>   why the data is invalid char, size is right.
```

> > > Source Code

```
Client.cpp

string strUrl = "http://109.123.121.146:8124/";
string strLog = "Hello,CURL!";

curl_easy_setopt(g_curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, strUrl.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(g_curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(g_curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, strLog.c_str());


Server.js

req.addListener('data', function (data) {
    body += data;
    console.log("Partial body: " + data + "  size:"+data.toString().length);
});

req.addListener('end', function () {
    console.log("Body: " + body + " size:"+body.toString().length);
});
```

I wonder why the request data is invalid char:"B=~�" , or not the right string "Hello,CURL!",

Anyone konws, help to explain to me,  thanks ~~~

Comment: log `data.toString()` and `body.toString()`?

Comment: yes, I want to convert the POST data to string,  then print it ~

Comment: no - I meant you're calling `console.log(data)` - try `console.log(data.toString())`

Comment: Thanks, EML ,  I did try to  use "toString()" , but the result is the same ....